# Contact page 404 error magento 2

Tags: magento2, 404-page, 404, contact-us

When ever i open contact us page it gives 404 error on white screen like this

> http://prntscr.com/nv27xs

the page is enabled form configuration.
 by default 404 error page is like this

> http://prntscr.com/nv298u

In error log

> http://prntscr.com/nv50lu

Comment: is other pages like category or  product opening ?

Comment: yes, all the other pages are working normally.

Comment: i just looked the error log and this is what i found http://prntscr.com/nv50lu

Comment: What url you are using to open contact us page? It should <website_url>/contact.

Comment: yes i am using aaa.com/contact

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157768)